# Mount usb hdd with exec

Tags: hard-drive, mount

I have a usb hdd that I am trying to mount with exec -- so I can run executable files from the disk.

In fstab I have:

```
/dev/sda1       /mnt/usbdisk    auto    rw,exec,user       0       1
```

But when I mount, I get

```
/dev/sda1 on /mnt/usbdisk type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,data=ordered,user)
```

And I cannot run executable files from the disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a tidbit from `man mount`:

> **user:** Allow an ordinary user to mount the filesystem.  [...]  This option implies the options noexec, nosuid, and nodev  (unless  overridden  by  subsequent
>                 options, as in the option line user,exec,dev,suid).

In case that's not clear, later arguments take precedence and by putting `user` last you've implicitly overridden `exec`.  Try it the other way around:

```
rw,user,exec
```